# How to set up a network connection with 2 ISP,s 2 Routers and 1 switch

Tags: router, switch, isp

I want to use 2 ISP providers at the same time, to avoid downtime. Here's a diagram of what I want to do:

[image: Network Setup Diagram]

What settings should I use for the routers and can I force PCs to use ISP#1 when online and ISP#2 when 1 is down?

Comment: That's a really pretty picture for such a poorly researched question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How you do it will depend on the routers you have. What you are trying to do is configure the routers in failover also known as high availability mode.

You can also you two ISPs with a single router and use WAN failover. You also are able to use a dedicated device to do link balancing and connection failover.

First, you need to determine what routers you are using and then I suggest looking for the terms above to find the configuration you need to build. If you have a specific question about how to do something please let me know.

Comment: One of my routers is Asus RT-AC68U and it supports Dual WAN. I suppose this is what you're talking about?

Comment: Yes that is one option. There are various ways to do what you want to. You can have two NICs on a single router and the router has link failover where one NIC with ISP1 cable connected to it is the primary and if the connection goes down a different NIC with ISP2 cable connected to it takes over. You can also have a dedicated server that both ISP cables plug into and it does failover. More commercial routers will let you have them connect to each other so if one router goes down the other router comes online.

Comment: I see. Appreciate that. Another question that you might help me with: Can i use Static IP settings provided to me from ISP#1, with ISP#2?

Comment: You are welcome. No, you cannot. You must use the IP address, gateway, and subnet mask given to you from each provider.

Comment: How do i do that, when using Dual WAN?

Comment: Go to WAN and Dual WAN and enter the information. https://www.asus.com/support/faq/1005714/

Comment: Oh i just saw that you can actually switch between the WAN Type (WAN/Ethernet LAN) to configure the IP settings. I think you solved it all. Thank you!

Comment: You are welcome! Good luck!